# Laravel 5 enum type fails while creating

Tags: php, mysql, enums, models, laravel-5

Really weird issue here. I'm generating an administrator for my website through the `\Console\Command` and at some point I obviously create it.

```
$user = User::create([

    'first_name' => 'Admin',
    'last_name' => 'Inistrator',
    'phone' => '',

    'email' => $email,
    'password' => bcrypt($password),
    'role' => 'admin',
]);
```

The result in my database is that the account got a `user` role instead of `admin`, but if I do this

```
$user = User::create([

    'first_name' => 'Admin',
    'last_name' => 'Inistrator',
    'phone' => '',

    'email' => $email,
    'password' => bcrypt($password),
    'role' => 'admin',

    ]);

$user->role = 'admin';
$user->save();
```

Then it works perfectly. I suspect Laravel 5 to do something weird while I create a new account, which would be linked with all the traits, etc. linked with the `User` model ... What do you think ?

*PS : Here's my migration table*

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {

            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->enum('role', ['user', 'business', 'admin']);

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {

        Schema::drop('users');

    }

}
```

Comment: I think the first step is to display the SQL queries executed. I didn't switch yet on laravel 5 so i don't know the line of code to display that, but i found that : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar, can you copy/paste the queries section ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. I listened the queries thank to the `DB::getQuerylog()` (I also could have used `DB::listen` as said in the answers)

The query is :

```
    \DB::enableQueryLog();

    $user = User::create([

        'first_name' => 'Admin',
        'last_name' => 'Inistrator',
        'phone' => '',

        'email' => $email,
        'password' => bcrypt($password),
        'role' => 'admin',

        ]);

    dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

And the result is :

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "insert into `users` (`email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    "bindings" => array:4 [
      0 => "klklm"
      1 => "$2y$10$RUorxAp4EbN/7TvEmdk.dudBBb0dgUWhmAvRsjXgVFubhEKbaLR4K"
      2 => "2015-04-13 10:30:36"
      3 => "2015-04-13 10:30:36"
    ]
    "time" => 3.17
 ]
]
```

So I realized my fields were simply ignored. I checked the model and saw I forgot to add the fields within `$fillable`

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
```

I added the other fields and it **works like a charm**. So if anyone got a similar problem the solution is pretty simple, don't forget to fill the `$fillable` array ;)

Answer (score 2):

Two things can happen,

1. either your `enum` value is not matching
2. or your column is not added to `$fillable` array

Answer (score 1):

Try this to listen queries:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time)
{
    //
});
```